# Conditional code depending on template parameters comparision

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-compilation

everybody! Want to make method compiling differently depending on template parameters.

```
template <unsigned long prec> class DFixed {
public:
  unsigned long val;
...
  template <unsigned long prec1> DFixed<prec> &operator-=(DFixed<prec1> d) {
    #if prec==prec1
    val -= d.val;
    #elif prec<prec1
    val -= d.val/(prec1/prec);
    #else
    val -= d.val*(prec/prec1);
    #endif
    return *this;
  }
...
};
```

But the code above calls block for prec==prec1 even for different precs.

Comment: Your mix of pre-processor and template programming does not work. Use `if ()` and `else` instead. Don't worry about the "dead code" paths. The compiler is (very) probably able to optimize them away. (Look at the assembly output if in doubt.) ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It works, but compiler complains on zero-division. It's warning, but that's, why I began trying preprocessor.
Do you know some way to compare template parameters at compilation time and do conditional compilation?

Comment: If you can use c++17 you can use if constexpr for this.

Comment: If you are sure that the branch with `prec == 0` (or `prec1 == 0`) is not active then I wouldn't care too much about the warning. It shows that the compiler really resolves `prec` and `prec1` to values (which is a pre-condition for the final optimization which eliminates the resp. if branches and even the `if ()`s themselves.)

Comment: Though: `else if (prec < prec1)` can indeed cause that branch becomes active with e.g. `prec == 0` and `prec1 > 0`. I'm afraid you have to modify your code (with additional `if` conditions) to prevent division by 0 properly. (Though the warning of the compiler was really justified.)

Comment: A zerodiv complain is for code, which never happends: it's when prec>prec1, but the line val -= d.val/(prec1/prec); still gets compiled and compiler have d.val/0. That is why I started to conditional-compile. But it's just for purity ;). Will just ignore the warning until try gcc7...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, C++17's [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) is the best solution:

```
template <unsigned long prec1>
DFixed & operator-=(DFixed<prec1> d) {
    if constexpr (prec==prec1)
        val -= d.val;
    else if constexpr (prec<prec1)
        val -= d.val/(prec1/prec);
    else
        val -= d.val*(prec/prec1);

    return *this;
}
```

If you're using C++11, you can use SFINAE with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) hidden in a REQUIRES macro:

```
#define REQUIRES(...) typename std::enable_if<(__VA_ARGS__), int>::type = 0
```

```
template <unsigned long prec1, REQUIRES(prec==prec1)>
DFixed & operator-=(DFixed<prec1> const & d) {
    val -= d.val;
    return *this;
}
template <unsigned long prec1, REQUIRES(prec<prec1)>
DFixed & operator-=(DFixed<prec1> const & d) {
    val -= d.val/(prec1/prec);
    return *this;
}
template <unsigned long prec1, REQUIRES(prec>prec1)>
DFixed & operator-=(DFixed<prec1> const & d) {
    val -= d.val*(prec/prec1);
    return *this;
}
```

Note that input parameter `d` is passed by `const` reference to avoid unnecessary copy.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use something like

```
if constexpr (prec == prec1) {
    // one branch
}
else {
    // other branch
}
```

`if constexpr` was introduced with C++17.

Comment: Thanks! Can I do something within C++11?

Comment: You can but it is annoying. For example, you can use specialization of a `struct` template (once for a template argument indicating the values are the same, once where they are different) and delegating to that. With C++14 you could use something like `std::condition` with two generic lambdas. Either way it can be done but it is somewhat annoying.